# AngularJS Mapping results from $http requests

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I've tried a few different ways trying to get this to work. So essentially I have a list of parks that I pull with one $http get method, each park object has a weather field inside of it. After the initial load I am trying to parse non-restful .json files with the weather status (pulled by a background process server side) and do an association with the weather object based on zipcode.
So there are about 30 parks. The way I pulled the weather info on the background (so as to not hit the rate limit) was to just pull them for each zipcode (relative to park location) and place them in a file named by zipcode. So for example 90201.json, 08291.json, etc

I've tried doing something like this so far:  http://plnkr.co/edit/66BjKESPnYGWgQwOzEPN?p=info

But I think I'm probably messing up in a few places, any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Check all the warnings and errors in plunkr, you have a few.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use plunkr too often, which warnings/errors are you talking about? I just wanted to paste the general idea of where I was going, I hacked at it for a while so it's kind of at the point of bastardization. I was simply posting on plunkr to try and convey the general direction of how I was trying to accomplish the mapping between multiple models via $http requests. Thanks for the reply.